# Match statement with explicit return of a borrowed reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

While taking a look at Rust I noticed a behavior I do not quite understand.

I've got this code, which works as expected:

```rust
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> String {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(x) => return x.clone(),
        None => ()
    }

    println!("creating foo");
    v.push("foo".to_string());
    v.get(0).unwrap().clone()
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    println!("{}", get_or_create_foo(&mut v));
    println!("{}", get_or_create_foo(&mut v));
}
```

When I change the `get_or_create_foo()` to make it return a borrowed string slice, the compiler refuses to compile it.

```rust
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(x) => return x,
        None => ()
    }

    println!("creating foo");
    v.push("foo".to_string());
    v.get(0).unwrap()
}
```

Compilation log:

```
$ rustc --verbose src/main.rs
src/main.rs:8:5: 8:6 error: cannot borrow `*v` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
src/main.rs:8     v.push("foo".to_string());
                  ^
src/main.rs:2:11: 2:12 note: previous borrow of `*v` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `*v` until the borrow ends
src/main.rs:2     match v.get(0) {
                        ^
src/main.rs:10:2: 10:2 note: previous borrow ends here
src/main.rs:1 fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
...
src/main.rs:10 }
               ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

In my understanding that code is valid: the mentioned borrow may be returned as soon as control leaves the `match` clause by taking the path leading to the code mutating `v`.

Am I wrong? Could anyone give an example when allowing such code would cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Rust myself too, but I believe I might have found the source of your problem.

You can inspect the type signature of "get" function [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.get). As you can see, "get" function returns a borrowed reference to the requested member of the vector (wrapped inside Option). My guess is that the compiler is unable to verify in your situation that "x" can not "escape" from match block.

Here is a simpler, but similar example from **[A 30-minute Introduction to Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/intro.html#ownership)**:

> ```
> fn main() {
>    let mut v = vec![];
>
>    v.push("Hello");
>
>    let x = &v[0];
>
>    v.push("world");
>
>    println!("{}", x);
> }
> ```
>
> In Rust, the type system encodes the notion of ownership. The variable v is an owner of the vector. When we make a reference to v, we let that variable (in this case, x) borrow it for a while. Just like if you own a book, and you lend it to me, I'm borrowing the book.
>
> So, when I try to modify the vector with the second call to push, I need to be owning it. But x is borrowing it. You can't modify something that you've lent to someone. And so Rust throws an error.

Here is how I am imaging it:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    let a: &str;

    match v.get(0) {
        Some(x) => {
            a = x;
            return x;
        },
        None => ()
    }

    // Now "a" is still borrowing "v" immutably!
    // println!("{:?}", a);

    println!("creating foo");
    v.push("foo".to_string());
    v.get(0).unwrap()
}
```

As I said I'm still a beginner so there might be more to this. I came to my conclusion after toying around with your code a bit.

A simple refactor would fix this problem:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    match v.get(0) {
        // Notice how the borrowed value is never used and
        // thus can not "escape" our match block.
        Some(_) => (),
        _       => v.push("foo".to_string())
    }
    
    // No need to use "get" here since we are 100% sure that
    // the indexed vector contains at least one item.
    return &v[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly, but I suspect that your code:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(x) => return x,
        None => ()
    }

    println!("creating foo");
    v.push("foo".to_string());
    v.get(0).unwrap()
}
```

is translated by the compiler into something with equivalent syntax by eliminating explicit `return`, like this:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    match v.get(0) {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => {
            println!("creating foo");
            v.push("foo".to_string());
            v.get(0).unwrap()
        },
    }
}
```

which obviously fails with the same error. Here `get` produces `Option<&String>`, so `v` remains borrowed even in `None` branch, where no reference is captured.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to rewrite the function:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    if v.get(0).is_none() {
        println!("creating foo");
        v.push("foo".to_string());
    }

    v.get(0).unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly improve swizard's solution:

```
fn get_or_create_foo(v: &mut Vec<String>) -> &str {
    if v.is_empty() {
        println!("creating foo");
        v.push("foo".to_string());        
    }

    &v[0]
}
```