# How to force rust to drop a mutable borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I force Rust borrow checker to forget about mutable borrow, with unsafe or not? I assumed that even lexical lifetimes should allow reusing mutable reference after a brackets block, but even Non-Lexical-Lifetimes from the fresh Rust release forbids that. With no outcome I tried some variants of unsafe and `std::mem::drop`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Storage {
    s: String,
    v: Vec<u8>,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Ret<'a> {
    S(&'a mut String),
    V(&'a mut Storage),
}

fn fake_get_s<'a, 'b:'a>(_unused_storage: &'b mut Storage) -> Option<&'a mut String> {
    None
}

fn get_ret<'a> (storage: &'a mut Storage) -> Ret<'a> {
    // Borrowed for a limited block, assuming to release..
    {
        match fake_get_s(storage) {
            Some(string_ref) => {
                return Ret::S(string_ref);
            }
            None => (),
        }
        // ..with no one keeping the borrow..
    }
    // ..but, surprisingly, I still can't borrow the origin variable
    // Ridiculous, right?
    Ret::V(storage)
}

fn main() {
    let mut storage = Storage{s: "string".to_string(), v: vec![1, 2, 3]};
    let res = get_ret(&mut storage);
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

[make sure this code does not compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Storage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20String%2C%0A%20%20%20%20v%3A%20Vec%3Cu8%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug)%5D%0Aenum%20Ret%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20S(%26%27a%20mut%20String)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20V(%26%27a%20mut%20Storage)%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20fake_get_s%3C%27a%2C%20%27b%3A%27a%3E(_unused_storage%3A%20%26%27b%20mut%20Storage)%20-%3E%20Option%3C%26%27a%20mut%20String%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20None%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20get_ret%3C%27a%3E%20(storage%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20Storage)%20-%3E%20Ret%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Borrowed%20for%20a%20limited%20block%2C%20assuming%20to%20release..%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20fake_get_s(storage)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(string_ref)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Ret%3A%3AS(string_ref)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20..with%20no%20one%20keeping%20the%20borrow..%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20..but%2C%20surprisingly%2C%20I%20still%20can%27t%20borrow%20the%20origin%20variable%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ridiculous%2C%20right%3F%0A%20%20%20%20Ret%3A%3AV(storage)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20storage%20%3D%20Storage%7Bs%3A%20%22string%22.to_string()%2C%20v%3A%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20get_ret(%26mut%20storage)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20res)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: I think this is a false positive in the borrow checker. You are not the first who reports this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905810/match-statement-with-explicit-return-of-a-borrowed-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sadly runs into a [known false positive in the borrow checker](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions).

At the time of writing, there is no way to fix this issue without `unsafe`. Luckily, there's a workaround crate that encapsulates the `unsafe` in a sound manner, called [polonius-the-crab](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/).

Here it is, applied to your code:

```rust
use polonius_the_crab::{polonius, polonius_return};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Storage {
    s: String,
    v: Vec<u8>,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Ret<'a> {
    S(&'a mut String),
    V(&'a mut Storage),
}

fn fake_get_s<'a, 'b: 'a>(_unused_storage: &'b mut Storage) -> Option<&'a mut String> {
    None
}

fn get_ret<'a>(mut storage: &'a mut Storage) -> Ret<'a> {
    polonius!(|storage| -> Ret<'polonius> {
        match fake_get_s(storage) {
            Some(string_ref) => {
                polonius_return!(Ret::S(string_ref));
            }
            None => (),
        }
    });

    Ret::V(storage)
}

fn main() {
    let mut storage = Storage {
        s: "string".to_string(),
        v: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    let res = get_ret(&mut storage);
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Note that `storage` now has to be a `mut` variable, because `polonius` borrows it indefinitely (like before), but then writes it back with the lifetime recovered through `unsafe`.

---

### Alternatives

One solution I've used myself already is to decouple the decision from the result computation by querying twice:

```rust
fn get_ret(storage: &mut Storage) -> Ret<'_> {
    if fake_get_s(storage).is_some() {
        return Ret::S(fake_get_s(storage).unwrap());
    }

    Ret::V(storage)
}
```

Or, if you **must** overwrite the borrow checker with `unsafe`:

```rust
fn get_ret(storage: &mut Storage) -> Ret<'_> {
    {
        let storage = unsafe { &mut *(storage as *mut Storage) };

        match fake_get_s(storage) {
            Some(string_ref) => {
                return Ret::S(string_ref);
            }
            None => (),
        }
    }

    Ret::V(storage)
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, add the unsafe variant of the solution? I hesitate adding a hotfix crate to the project for a single issue. Thanks

Comment: It's quite complicated. I'd recomment reading the [polonius-the-crab](https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/) website, it goes into much detail about what the problem is and how they solved it.

Comment: @makaleks I added an `unsafe` version. I think (tm) it works fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've never heard this called "the polonius problem". Yes its a problem that [polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) is designed to solve, but I've only heard the issue itself called [non-lexical lifetimes: problem #3](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#problem-case-3-conditional-control-flow-across-functions).

Comment: @kmdreko, does rust team know the problem was not solved in the August nll-migration release? What is the issue number? Now I see the nll tracking issue is closed, but there multiple duplicates and all I saw are also closed(

Comment: @makaleks see this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663

Comment: @Finomnis note that your unsafe solution is [UB according to MIRI](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b73f7031ecaae5955e3aa8503d6150bc).

Comment: @Jmb fixed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bae04b615314e3e414cd78fe162ffabc. Will update in the answer.